# Regex matching whats inside quotes but not the same quote inside the line

Tags: javascript, regex, match, eval

I've been trying this regex`/(['])((?:(?!\1)[^\\]|(?:\\\\)*\\[^\\])*)\1/` to gather in an array of list of "variables" from a `GET` response.

The string looks like :

```
  "var chatbox_messages='<p class="chatbox_row_1 clearfix"><span title="17 Feb 2014">[20:46:07]</span>&nbsp;<span style="font-style:italic">You are disconnected.</span></span></p>';var chatbox_memberlist='<h4 class="member-title online">Online</h4><ul class="online-users"><li><a href="/u1" oncontextmenu="return showMenu(1,'Admin',1,2,1,2,1,event,'');" onclick="return copy_user_name('Admin');" target="_blank"><span style="color:#000099"><strong>@</strong></span>&nbsp;<span style="color:#000099"><strong>Admin</strong></span></a></li></ul>';var chatbox_last_update=1392687967.7403; "
```

The strings above are together just the have x overflow and it's annoying...

Anyways the user who code this code before me was using `eval` and I don't use eval so I'm trying to fix the code and get the parameters so that I can just do

```
var response = responseText.match(/(['])((?:(?!\1)[^\\]|(?:\\\\)*\\[^\\])*)\1/g);
    var message = response[0];
    var second_message = response[1];
```

Though none of the regex I am using will get exactly what I need! It either separates the variable from string into pieces of the array or it still grabs the first quotes `'` and I don't want them at all...

Can anyone help me or lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Please fix your string.  As is, it produces tons of errors and makes it more confusing to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @Anonymous fixed it, I added the real string in there for you

Comment: IT still has syntax errors but this is how I receive it from the DB

Comment: Where do you want it separated?  Never mind, I think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

just do this on your match:

```
var newMatchWithoutQuotes=match.replace("'","");
```

This will remove the quotes;

Comment: yes this would but it doesn't fix the `["'<span class=\"doodle\"></span><div class=\"monkey\" onclick=\"doStuff(","'alpha","')\"></div>"];`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you mean to escape the double quotes:

```
"var chatbox_messages='<p class=\"chatbox_row_1 clearfix\"><span title=\"17 Feb 2014\">[20:46:07]</span>&nbsp;<span style=\"font-style:italic\">You are disconnected.</span></span></p>';var chatbox_memberlist='<h4 class=\"member-title online\">Online</h4><ul class=\"online-users\"><li><a href=\"/u1\" oncontextmenu=\"return showMenu(1,'Admin',1,2,1,2,1,event,'');\" onclick=\"return copy_user_name('Admin');\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"color:#000099\"><strong>@</strong></span>&nbsp;<span style=\"color:#000099\"><strong>Admin</strong></span></a></li></ul>';var chatbox_last_update=1392687967.7403; "
```

You can simply use this regex if the string will **always** end in `';`:

```
/'.*?';/
```

Comment: this is what I get `"'chatbox_messenger_form').style.display='none';", "'<p class=\"chatbox_row_1 clearfix\"><span title=\"17 Feb 2014\">[21:55:02]</span>&nbsp;<span style=\"font-style:italic\">You are disconnected.</span></span></p>';"`;
I've also tried `/'(.*?)'/g` both output the same

Comment: If this isn't going to work, I suppose I can eval it though I don't want to

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not using it right if that is the result.  What is the full code that you are using to test this?